# MYSQL Query a table with a set condition and if a 2nd conidtion is met grab a row(s) from another table and continue

Tags: mysql

I am hoping it is possible to; within a SQL query, switch to a second table; if a certain condition is made, grab the relevant row data and then continue completing the prior query?

I have a table `cms_navbar` which gets queried and pulls back all rows if the column `visible` == 1. What I am looking to add is for the query to jump to another table; `cms_navbar_preview`, if `$_GET['id_hash']` is equal to the `hash` column in `cms_navbar`, grab all rows from `cms_navbar_preview` where `live_hash` == `$_GET['id_hash']` and finally continue running through the remaining rows within `cms_navbar` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM cms_navbar
WHERE visible=1
AND parent=1
ORDER BY position ASC
```

Sorry if this struggles to get my point across.

CMS_NAVBAR Table:

```
id | title | link | visible | position | parent | child | relation | hash
```

CMS_NAVBAR_PREVIEW Table:

```
id | title | link | visible | position | parent | child | relation | live_hash | showcase_content
```

Comment: How many fields are the in the tables?  There is a way to do this, but could be tedious if a large number of fields...

Comment: column names for both tables now in OP edit.

Comment: @DanielWrigley One of these tags is incorrect.  Please read the tag pop-outs before posting.  Are you working with MySQL or SQL Server (which uses MSSQL)?

Comment: @BLaZuRE apologies with the tags, it is MySQL I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT 
  IFNULL(nbp.id,nb.id) as ID,
  IFNULL(nbp.title,nb.title) as TITLE,
  etc....

  FROM cms_navbar nb
  LEFT JOIN cms_navbar_preview nbp ON nbp.live_hash= <parameter> AND nb.id=nbp.id
    WHERE nb.visible=1
    AND nb.parent=1
    ORDER BY nb.position ASC
```

Basically, you join the preview table on your condition.   If you find a match, pull the fields from the preview table.   If not (i.e. NULL), pull the field from the navbar table.

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: integrating this into my code, will let you know how it goes, ty.

Comment: Update: I have got the data from the table cms_navbar_preview to come back but ATM it updates every item within that group of links. e.g. if the top level links are `products`, `service` & `shop` and I edit `shop` to "shop test" the other prior 2 come back as "shop test" also.

Comment: Can you create an SQLFiddle with some sample data?

Comment: SQL Fiddle is a web application that lets you define your schema, load sample data, and indicate which SQL dialect you are using.   Then you can try out different queries and let other people tweak the queries as well.   Definitely a helpful tool for tweaking queries

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0caea/2 I have finally got this up for you to look at, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Try adding this:   and nb.id=nbp.id   after the live_hash clause (see modified query in answer)